# Is there any downside to Django proxy models?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting rather tired of paging through lots of irrelevant little fiddly properties while looking for the actual database structure of my models. Would it be a bad thing to use proxy models universally just to keep my code better organized / more readable? I.e.

```
class Foo_Base( models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( ...)
    # other DB fields. As little as possible anything else.
class Bar_Base( models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey( Foo_Base, ... )
```

etc. not many more lines than there are columns in the DB tables. Then at the bottom or elsewhere,

```
class Foo( Foo_Base):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    @property
    def some_pseudo_field(self):
        # compute something based on the DB fields in Foo_Base
        return result
    @property
    # etc. pages of etc.
```

The fact that `makemigrations` and `migrate` tracks proxy models makes me slightly concerned, although this usage seems to be exactly what the Django documentation says they are for (wrapping extra functionality around the same database table).

Or is there another way to organize my code that accomplishes the same (keeping fundamental stuff and fiddly little support bits apart).

[Edit] am offering up something that seems to work as a self-answer below. I'd still very much like to hear from anybody who knows for a fact that this is OK, given the deep Django magic on its declarative field declarations.

(About the only thing I dislike about Python, is that it does not have  `include` functionality for reading in a heap of code from another file! )

Comment: Are you intending to have 1:1 relationship between base and proxy?

Comment: @grrrrrr Yes (hope I counted the r's in grrrrrr right!)

Comment: ;) in my opinion this seems like it deviates from the technical intention of proxy models to accomplish an aesthetic goal. with that in mind although it may *work* it may confuse other devs or increase technical debt down the road. personally i would consider (custom) code folding to hide fields / properties / methods by group instead

Comment: @grrrrrr offering my own experimentally determined answer. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer: use a plugin class inheriting from `object`, 
as is commonplace for class-based Views.

I'd still very much like to hear from anybody who knows for a fact that this is OK, given the deep Django magic on its declarative field declarations.

Minimal proof of concept:

```
class PenMethods1( object):
    @property
    def namey(self):
        return format_html('<div class="namey">{name}</div>', name=self.name )

class PenTest1(PenMethods1, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=16, blank=True )
    def __repr__(self):
       return f'<Pentest1 object id={self.id} name={self.name}>'
```

Initial migration was OK. Then I added

```
pnum = models.ForeignKey( 'Pennum', models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

(`Pennum` was something already lying around in my playpen) and ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Again OK and basic functioning checks out...

```
>>> from playpen.models import PenTest1, Pennum
>>> n = Pennum.objects.last()
>>> n
<Pennum object id=3 name="t3" num=14 >
>>> p = PenTest1.objects.get(name='bar')
>>> p
<Pentest1 object id=2 name=bar>
>>> p.namey
'<div class="namey">bar</div>'
>>> p.pnum=n
>>> p.save()
>>> n=Pennum.objects.last()
>>> list(n.pentest1_set.all())
[<Pentest1 object id=2 name=bar>]
>>>
```

Comment: This seems to be hacky as I don't see any examples of this in the Django docs. If you are intent on having it broken out like this you should use either Abstract base models or Proxy Models.

Comment: On the other hand, it is standard Python with no obvious Django implications.

Comment: But there again, having added such a model, you can't remove it in a completely straightforward manner because the initial migration records the plugin class and subsequent migrations fail if it has vanished, even after you have removed the model into which it was plugged. You can stub it out to a single `pass` statement, though.

Comment: @grrrrr can an abstract base class inherit from another abstract base class? Otherwise, that  doesn't help.